# Function for conditional for loop

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements

Ok, this is the complete code that I'm working with. Now I've provided input and output. Hope it makes more sense that my absurd questions earlier.....

```
def get_positions(xs, item):    
    if isinstance(xs, list):
        for i, it in enumerate(xs):
            for pos in get_positions(it, item):
                yield (i,) + pos
    elif xs == item:
        yield ()
blocks = [-12,-10,-8,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16]
startcombos = [[-12], [-12, -10], [-12, -10, -8], [-12, -10, -8, -6], [-12, -10, -8, -6, -4], [-12, -10,-8, -6, -4, -2], [-12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0], [-12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2], [-12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4], [-12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6], [-12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [-12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [-12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12], [-12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14], [-12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16]]
combos = [[-10], [-10, -8], [-10, -8, -6], [-10, -8, -6, -4], [-10, -8, -6, -4, -2], [-10, -8, -6,-4, -2, 0], [-10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2], [-10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4], [-10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6], [-10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [-10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6,8, 10], [-10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12], [-10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14], [-10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16], [-8], [-8, -6], [-8, -6, -4], [-8, -6, -4, -2], [-8, -6, -4, -2, 0], [-8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2], [-8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4], [-8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6], [-8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [-8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [-8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12], [-8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14], [-8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16], [-6], [-6, -4], [-6, -4, -2], [-6, -4, -2, 0], [-6, -4, -2, 0, 2], [-6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4], [-6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6], [-6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [-6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [-6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12], [-6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14], [-6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16], [-4], [-4, -2], [-4, -2, 0], [-4, -2, 0, 2], [-4, -2, 0, 2, 4], [-4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6],[-4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [-4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [-4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12], [-4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14], [-4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16], [-2], [-2, 0],[-2, 0, 2], [-2, 0, 2, 4], [-2, 0, 2, 4, 6], [-2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [-2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [-2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12], [-2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14], [-2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16], [0], [0, 2], [0, 2, 4], [0, 2, 4, 6], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [0,2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16], [2], [2, 4], [2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6, 8], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16], [4], [4, 6], [4, 6, 8], [4, 6, 8, 10], [4, 6, 8, 10,12], [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14], [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16], [6], [6, 8], [6, 8, 10], [6, 8, 10, 12], [6, 8, 10, 12, 14], [6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16], [8], [8, 10], [8, 10, 12], [8, 10, 12, 14], [8, 10, 12, 14, 16], [10], [10, 12], [10, 12, 14], [10, 12, 14, 16], [12], [12, 14], [12, 14, 16], [14], [14, 16], [16]]

temp = []
for i in range(len(startcombos)):   
    for j in list(get_positions(combos,startcombos[i][-1]+2)):
        if j[-1]==0 and combos[j[0]][-1]!=blocks[-1]:

            for k in list(get_positions(combos,combos[j[0]][-1]+2)):                
                if k[-1]==0 and combos[k[0]][-1]!=blocks[-1]:

                    for l in list(get_positions(combos,combos[k[0]][-1]+2)):
                        if l[-1]==0 and combos[l[0]][-1]==blocks[-1]:
                            temp.append(tuple(startcombos[i]))
                            temp.append(tuple(combos[j[0]]))
                            temp.append(tuple(combos[k[0]]))
                            temp.append(tuple(combos[l[0]]))
                            combinations.append(temp)
                            temp = []
```

This is a code to generate temp of length 4. If the length of combinations increases, I would include another condition inside the bigger loop like this

```
for i in range(len(startcombos)):   
    for j in list(get_positions(combos,startcombos[i][-1]+2)):
        if j[-1]==0 and combos[j[0]][-1]!=blocks[-1]:

            for k in list(get_positions(combos,combos[j[0]][-1]+2)):                
                if k[-1]==0 and combos[k[0]][-1]!=blocks[-1]:               

                    for l in list(get_positions(combos,combos[k[0]][-1]+2)):
                        if l[-1]==0 and combos[l[0]][-1]!=blocks[-1]:

                            for m in list(get_positions(combos,combos[l[0]][-1]+2)):
                                if m[-1]==0 and combos[m[0]][-1]==blocks[-1]:
                                    temp.append(tuple(startcombos[i]))
                                    temp.append(tuple(combos[j[0]]))
                                    temp.append(tuple(combos[k[0]]))
                                    temp.append(tuple(combos[l[0]]))
                                    temp.append(tuple(combos[m[0]]))                                        
                                    combinations.append(temp)
                                    temp = []
```

This will generate a temp with length 5. As you have noticed the first and last conditions and loops changes, the middle part remains the same. How to write a function or any other way that I can achieve it with variable lengths?

Now what I would get here is basically combinations which is obtained by providing specific conditions. I know that I could try python combinations from itertools but generating all combinations is simply not worth it if I want specific combinations and besides computational time is also important. Thus, it would give the following output for length 4

```
combinations[0] = [[-12],[-10],[-8],[-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16]]
```

and so on which are 364 in number.

For length 5, it will give a total of 1001 combinations of which the first one is this

```
combinations[0] = [[-12],[-10],[-8],[-6],[-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16]]
```

Comment: (a) it's not clear what you want to achieve; (b) what have you tried to do to achieve this, anyway?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wants to achieve variable-depth for-loops. Not really that unclear, and he did provide a code example. What's the problem, guys?

Comment: Yes.. Pardon me that I'm not a hardcore programmer and thus unfamiliar with how to describe a problem to a fellow programmer in specific terminologies. I've tried to find a solution using functions but it fails to remember the previous variables like i,j etc...

Comment: @bioinfoboy: If you want you can [edit] your question and insert your attemp of function there.

Comment: @FrancisW.Usher His attempts are also illuminating of what he wants to achieve.

Comment: I agree that the question is not very clear... do you want to generate the sequence shown below? What does len(a) in your code refer to?

Comment: Would you mind posting the desired output for a certain input?

Comment: Whoa, I apologize guys, this question is way more convoluted than I thought. :P

Comment: @FrancisW.Usher: I was just pointing out the option to add more information since the OP [seemed willingfull](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963612/function-for-conditional-for-loop#comment12726598_9963612) to add them. And since there were a couple of requests for more information, I'd say that it's no harm in provide them.

Comment: @RikPoggi you're right, I came too quickly to the defense of the underdog. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: I've updated the question on the exact problem that I'm working on.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not totally sure I've interpreted your problem correctly; however what follows is a fairly general exercise which should serve to enlighten you somewhat either way. For the purposes of discussion here I'll assume that you're aiming at doing an arbitrary number of nested for-loops.

First, though, let me just satisfy the Pythonistas reading this by saying that the Pythonic way of doing this probably involves using the function [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and probably the built-in `filter()` function.

That aside, I think you should familiarize yourself with the concept of **recursion**, because it allows you to sort of "naively" come up with simple solutions to problems like this without having to rely on a sweet-ass language like Python to give you an awesome library full of generator functions.

Let's say you've got some lists in some list-of-lists, like:

```
nested = [[a1, a2, a3, ..., ana],
          [b1, b2, b3, ..., bnb],
          ...
          [x1, x2, x3, ..., xnx]]
```

And you want to iterate *pseudo-lexographically* through sequences which contain a single element from each of these lists, like:

```
a1 b1 c1 ... x1
a1 b1 c1 ... x2
...
a2 b1 c1 ... x1
a2 b1 c1 ... x2
...
...
ana bnb cnc ... x(nx - 1)
ana bnb cnc ... xnx
```

It's tough to do this with normal static for-loops because you usually have to type each one out, right? How do you type out some variable number of for-loops? A sort of naive trick to do this is using **recursion** (again this is not the most Pythonic way).

Recursion says, "okay, I have a problem. This problem is basically just doing something small with a part of my data, and then ***recursively*** solving the same problem on the rest of the data. When I have no more data to work with, I'm probably done with this sub-problem."

A simple, classic example of recursion is in computing a sum of a list of numbers:

```
def sum_nums(nums):
    # The "base case" is usually checked first. This is when your
    # recursion has run out of things to do, it just returns a simple value.
    if nums == []:
        return 0
    # The "recursive case" is the real meat and potatoes of recursion.
    # It says to take the first number and add it to the sum_nums of the
    # rest of the numbers in the list (which may be empty, hence the base case!).
    else:
        return nums[0] + sum_nums(nums[1:])
```

Think about this. Understand it. Meditate on it, and forget that you understand it. Do some psychedelics and think about it again. It's pretty important to be able to pull recursive hacks out of your ass on the fly.

Now a more advanced technique is to pass down values in a recursive function. In this case it can be useful because you don't want to do anything until you get down to the base case. I've left out the base case for you to implement yourself, if you care to do so.

```
def print_lexo_lists(items, lists):
    if lists == []:
        # What do you want to do if you've taken a single item from each of your
        # lists and put it in the list called "items"?
    else:
        # Take each item from the current level and pass it down in turn to the
        # next deeper level, adding it to the running list of "items". Remove
        # the current level from the list of "lists" before passing it down.
        # In this way you're "using up" the current level, and the "lists"
        # structure is getting smaller at each level of recursive depth, until
        # you reach the base case (when it is an empty list)
        for current_item in lists[0]:
            print_lexo_lists(items + [current_item], lists[1:])
```

Hope you can follow that to some extent. I highly recommend that you implement that before trying the following way, which is really the *correct* way of doing uber-nested for-loops in Python by generating the ***Cartesian Product*** of the lists:

```
from itertools import product
for items in product(*lists):
    print ' '.join(items)
```